# Node.js Selenium Webdriver wait/until doesn't appear to be working as expected

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

New to Selenium automated testing scripts, trying to create a deterministic script to test a password protected site. I can bring up the login page and send the user/pass values and click the login button without an issue, however, after that step my script errors out that an element is not able to be located. I am trying to utilize a wait/until approach to determine that elements are available, before interacting with them.

Below is a sample of stripped down code to illustrate my approach.

```
driver.get('https://somedomain.com/folders/login.php');
driver.wait(until.titleIs('Login Page'), 1 * 60 * 1000);
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('input1'), 1 * 60 * 1000)).then(driver.findElement(By.id('input1')).sendKeys('XXXXX'));
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('input2'), 1 * 60 * 1000)).then(driver.findElement(By.id('input2')).sendKeys('XXXXX'));
driver.findElement(By.id('inputBtn')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('Selection page'), 5 * 60 * 1000);
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('input3'), 5 * 60 * 1000));
driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('cssLoader'))), 5 * 60 * 1000);
driver.findElement(By.id('input3')).click();
```

I get the following errors:

```
(node:1452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="cssLoader"]"}
(node:1452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="input3"]"}
```

I see the errors in my console before the login process has completed. I had previously increased all the wait timeouts, thinking that was part of the issue, but that seems to not have been the case.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and would love to know the answer to this.

Comment: same issue here